# How to make 2 applications shared the same dock tile

Tags: macos, exec, fork, dock

I have a launcher application in a bundle in `/Applications` that chooses a binary and fork/execs it. What I would like is for them to share a dock tile. I have tried a few approaches and none of them are satisfactory.

**1. Keep the binary bundled with the app**

If the binary is contained within the app bundle, this seems to work. However, it's generally considered bad practice for a bundle to modify itself, and I can't guarantee that a user has write access to `/Applications`. I tried putting a symlink to e.g. `~/Library/Application Support/MyBinaries/mybinary` but this gives a separate dock tile.

**2. Keep the binary outside the app bundle**

If the binary is outside the app bundle, I get a separate dock tile. Why don't I set one of the processes to be an agent s.t. one of the tiles does not appear? This would have to be the launcher as the user should not be able to skip the launcher's logic as to which binary to run. Unfortunately this means that quit doesn't work properly, and you can't click the dock to restore the binary's window. It may be possible to get this to work by passing messages between the applications properly.

**3. Massively hacky solution**

There's a rather hacky way of doing this by adding an extra level of indirection, where the app at `/Applications/MyLauncher.app` launches another app in `~/Library/Application Support/Launcher2.app`, which contains the binaries in its bundle. Only the second launcher has a dock icon.

This seems rather hacky, so I thought I would open this up to SO to see if anyone has a better solution?

**EDIT**

In option 2, I was keeping the binaries in bundles of their own. Don't do this. When I kept them in a regular folder everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

If you find yourself in this situation, go with option 2. Put the application at `/Applications/MyApplication.app` and keep the binaries in a folder named something like `~/Library/Application Support/MyApplication/Binaries/` and happily fork/exec them. Definitely do not put them in app bundles, as this was the source of my confusion. This solved all of my criteria:

- Don't need root access to modify the binaries
- Launcher and binaries share one dock tile
- Pressing quit on the dock tile quits the binary.
- App appears in Launchpad
- Launching via Dock goes through the launcher app